# KDE with plasma 5 doesn't automount the partitions anymore on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, kubuntu

Until recently, kde was autommounting all my partitions after I was logging in.

But, after an upgrade (a few months ago), this stopped happening and now I use krusader to manually mount the patitions (I access each one of them and they get mounted).

I'm tired of doing this and I was wondering if someone knows what happened and if there is a fix for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it wasn't that hard after all.

I found this solution that worked perfectly: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?68092-Secondary-hard-drive-won-t-auto-mount&p=371603&viewfull=1#post371603.

TLDR version:

- Change the /usr/share/kde4/services/kded/device_automounter.desktop line X-KDE-Kded-phase=1 to X-KDE-Kded-phase=0
- Open "kcmshell4 kcmkded" and start 'Removable Device Automounter'
- Open "kcmshell4 device_automounter_kcm" and pick the right options from the KDE 'Removable Devices module'

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where the error is comming from, but you can always add a line to your /etc/fstab to solve it :)

```
UUID={partition UUID} {partition mount_point}  {partition type}    {options}  0       1
```

As an example, my main partition is mounted with these parameters:

```
UUID=a1e37f31-800a-481b-b039-d79087a2ffed  /  ext4 errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Comment: I don't want to take care of fstab. I'm trying to find a solution that will do it automatically.